# Camera View goes Purple when adding Video file as background for camera

Tags: 3d-view, camera

When I add a video file as background in the camera view. it works fine for a few frames (Upto 54) and then the camera view goes Purple (from 54 to 180 frames). What can be the issue. Adding both photos.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your video long enough? How long does it last, how many frames?

Comment: Video is 10 Secs Long and it last for 54 frames out of 180. After 54 frames it turns purple.